# Mysql Master-Slave reaplication with AUTO_INCREMENT primary key

Tags: mysql, master-slave

The problem is with standard `Mysql` `Master-Slave` setup (slave is read-only, binary logging is set to ROW), when one row is inserted in Master table with auto increment primary key, and this row, for example, gets `ID 4288996`, when the same insert is replicated at slave, the same row gets different `ID` e.g. `4289032` (because insert is issued without primary key value, which is autogenerated).

Now the problem rise when `UPDATE` statement is issued at this row at Master:

```
#180430 18:00:12 server id 1  end_log_pos 429933 CRC32 0xd0d85778
Update_rows: table id 260 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE `cmon`.`simple_alarm`
### WHERE
###   @1=4288996
### SET
###   @13=1525104012
###   @15=1
# at 429933
#180430 18:00:12 server id 1  end_log_pos 429964 CRC32 0xdc9f3fa4       Xid = 452035
```

Because the same row does not exist on Slave (have different ID):

> 'Could not execute Update_rows event on table cmon.simple_alarm; Can't find record in 'simple_alarm', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log xxxxx_bin_log.000003, end_log_pos 429933'

I know why this is a problem, but I don't have idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Master slave with different auto_incremented P.K itself an other issue. I think you should completely sync both tables including P.K field and their auto_increment values before debugging this issue. However below answer may solve I strongly advice you to create new slave completely identical with same replication setup and try your update statement and see if it is a leaking desync issue.

Comment: I just found out that each slave decides separately to invoke the change or not. If new id already exists in slave it can not invoke the change

Answer (score 0):

Known issue

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Replication and AUTO_INCREMENT
17.4.1.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html)

> A statement invoking a trigger or function that causes an update to an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column is not replicated correctly using
>   **statement-based replication**. These statements are marked as unsafe.
>   (Bug #45677)

Try row-based logging or mixed type. Maybe it will be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already using ROW based logging, and same problem appears:
binlog_format                  = ROW

Comment: @Goran Did you try the stuff in comments ?

Comment: Yes, I synced slave to master multiple times. And as soon new entry is added to cmon.simple_alarm table desync occurs. I'm using following steps: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

Comment: Can you insert new row and run this on both tables and see if results are the same ? SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: Do not specify auto_incremented id again (which i assume is the KEY)

Comment: This is now result of `select alarm_id from cmon.simple_alarm;` on Slave:
    "1"
    "4279416"
    "4288318"
    "4288349"
    "4289023"
    "4297593"
    "4297596"
    "4299500"
    "4299501"

And this on master:
"1"
"4279416"
"4288349"
"4328650"
"4327762"
"4288318"
"4327760"

As you can see, this table is all in desync.

Comment: ALTER TABLE masterTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 9999990; (Same statement for slave table just in case)
& Insert new row on master (Dont specify id like u always do) 
& SELECT MAX (id) FROM master.alarm ; SELECT MAX (id) FROM slave.alarm ; (If both are same good to go) 
& UPDATE master.alarm SET id= 9999996 WHERE id= 9999990 & and see if it is still broken ?

Comment: And slave is showing OK status:

"Waiting for master to send event" "Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates"

Comment: It is most possibly caused by Master and Slave with different P.Keys

Comment: I just issued `delete from cmon.simple_alarm;` and empty whole table. Again, same table on slave is not empty (stayed the same with 9 rows) and replication stopped:

`SQL Thread STOPPED (err: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table cmon.simple_alarm; Can't find record in 'simple_alarm', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log xxxxxx_bin_log.000003, end_log_pos 199526693, errno: 1032)
IO Thread RUNNING.`

Comment: It is normal slave does not have that id therefore it can not do that operation. These tables are not identical. ID colums must be same in order to that operation.

Comment: Yes, that is true. This table and all operations on it is managed by ClusterControl software (https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol), and I cannot change it (modify table and/or change SQL query).

Comment: I just did that. Also truncate master simple_alarm table before replicating. Now I have empty tables on both master and slave. And next auto_increment value shows 1 on both systems.
Now I'll start cmon service (that inserts data to that table and see what happens).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As soon as I start cmon process, table on Master (simple_alarm) is filled with rows, and none of that gets replicated to slave. So table on master now has 6 rows and on slave it is still empty :)
I really can't understand this.

Slave status shows that everything is replicated: `Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates` - Seconds behind master: 0

Comment: Strange, just found out that if I manually insert some data to table, that gets replicated correctly, but when application insert rows that doesn't get replicated at all... Very strange...

Comment: well, congrats you just found a bug in severalnines automation

Comment: Apparently whole database 'cmon' isn't replicating insert statemens issued by Severalnines ClusterControl app, not just specified table. Other database used in ClusterControl 'dcps' gets replicated without issue.
I still can't understand how this is possible thou.

Comment: Can you insert before replication. If so insert your own rows then start replication lets see if automated insert will be replicated along with yours or only yours.

Comment: Only mine inserts are replicated. Still no inserts from application.

Comment: I never saw a distributed system before however this one already smells like bleeding edge non-sense platform filled with work arounds. Good luck mate